# How to normalize only certain columns in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

I have data similar to the following:

```
[
   [0, 4, 15]
   [0, 3, 7]
   [1, 5, 9]
   [2, 4, 15]
]
```

I used `oneHotEncoder` http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.fit_transform to preprocess this data so it is suitable for linear regression to give me this:

```
[
   [1, 0, 0, 4, 15]
   [1, 0, 0, 3, 7]
   [0, 1, 0, 5, 9]
   [0, 0, 1, 4, 15]
]
```

However, I then wish to normalise this data.

So far I am just normalising the data like so:

```
preprocessing.normalize(data)
```

However, this normalises all the columns including category ones.

My questions are the following:

- How do I normalise only certain columns?
- Is it desirable to normalise category data, or should I avoid it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) to pass a slice of your data to `normalize`.  As for your question about normalizing category data, you will probably get a better answer to that question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Example for your first question:

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np
        from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

        # Values as floats or normalize raises a type error
        X1 = np.array([
                      [1., 0., 0., 4., 15.],
                      [1., 0., 0., 3., 7.],
                      [0., 1., 0., 5., 9.],
                      [0., 0., 1., 4., 15.],
                      ])

In [2]: X1[:, [3,4]] # last two columns
Out[2]: array([[  4.,  15.],
               [  3.,   7.],
               [  5.,   9.],
               [  4.,  15.]])
```

Normalize the last two columns and assign to a new numpy array, `X2`.

```py
In [3]: X2 = normalize(X1[:, [3,4]], axis=0) #axis=0 for column-wise
        X2
Out[3]: array([[ 0.49236596,  0.6228411 ],
               [ 0.36927447,  0.29065918],
               [ 0.61545745,  0.37370466],
               [ 0.49236596,  0.6228411 ]])
```

Now concatenate `X1` and `X2` for your desired output.

```py
In [4]: np.concatenate(( X1[:,[0,1,2]], X2), axis=1)
Out[4]: array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.49236596,  0.6228411 ],
               [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.36927447,  0.29065918],
               [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.61545745,  0.37370466],
               [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.49236596,  0.6228411 ]])
```

Comment: Dear @kevin, how to apply a min-max normalization that will yield maximum normalized value = 1 and minimum normalized value = 0? Neither argument for 'norm' (l1, l2 or max) seems to work. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `pandas.DataFrame`, you might want to check [sklearn-pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/sklearn-pandas).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler function to scale your data to a maximum value = 1 and a minimum value = 0. You can see the documentation here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler

Comment: how is this different from the other answers?